# Discord command bot doesn't responde (python)

Tags: python, command, discord.py, bots

i have a problem with my discord bot: when i type on discord $ping he doesn't response me pong and i don't know why, i just check the bot have the admin role so he can write, i'm using VsCode and he didn't give me nothing error.
Here is the code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json
import random

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Comment: You are mixing `client` and `bot`, do not do that... This is why the command is not working.

Comment: So what i need to delete? client =discord.Client() andall@client event?

Comment: Yes, you can delete `client = discord.Client()` and use `bot.event` and `bot.command()`. To run the bot use `bot.run("Token")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are defining the command with `bot.command`, but you only do `client.run`. To fix this, either choose a client, or a bot, but not both, like this if you choose bot for example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("pong")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    
bot.run(Token)
```

Also don't use requests, since it's blocking.

Comment: @Luigi2201 Could you accept the answer (with the green checkmark) if it worked for you, so others can quickly see that it works?

Comment: I just do it now